# What do the numbers in the "@@" line mean in output of diff?

Tags: diff

Here is an example of Unix Shell program `diff`, from Version Control with Git, by Loeliger, 2ed:

[image]

> Let’s look at the diff in detail.
>
> In the header, the original file is denoted by - - - and the new file
>   by +++.
>
> The @@ line provides line number context for both file versions.

What do the numbers in the "@@" line mean exactly?

Answer (score 8):

They are line-numbers for the old/new files to help the `patch` (or similar) program decode the unified-diff.

- The number after the comma is the length of the chunk (in the old or new file), and
- the number before the comma is the line number for the beginning of the chunk.
- The `+` and `-` signs refer to adding and deleting lines, respectively.

In your example, the line

```
@@ -1,4 +1,5 @@
```

uses the `-` and `+` signs as an analogy for the `<` and `>` signs used in the *normal diff* output for the left/right files.  Both of those formats attempt to interleave lines of difference.  (A context diff shows before- and after-chunks, not interleaving).

Unified diff is a particular format of the `diff` program; other widely-supported formats are discussed in the [diff Output Formats](http://www.chemie.fu-berlin.de/chemnet/use/info/diff/diff_3.html) section.

Further reading:

- [2.2.2.2 Detailed Description of Unified Format](http://www.gnu.org/software/diffutils/manual/html_node/Detailed-Unified.html)
- [How to read a patch or diff and understand its structure to apply it manually](http://www.markusbe.com/2009/12/how-to-read-a-patch-or-diff-and-understand-its-structure-to-apply-it-manually/)
- [diff Output Formats](http://www.chemie.fu-berlin.de/chemnet/use/info/diff/diff_3.html)
- [diff](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/diff.html) (POSIX)

Comment: THanks. (1) What is "unified-diff"? Are there other types of diff? (2) what do the signs in  "-1" and "+1" mean? the original file and the other file?

Comment: @Tim there are three "modes" for `diff`: *normal*, *unified* and *context*. First one is default for interactive purpose, last two are useful for patches and the like. Manual of `diff` is extensive, all detailed description is there.

Comment: Thanks. Let me clarify my (2): In your edit, "the number before the comma is the line number for the beginning of the chunk."  what do the signs in these numbers (e.g. "-1" and "+1") mean? the original file and the other file?  (I assume your "The + and - signs refer to adding and deleting lines, respectively" apply to the lines after the @@ line.)

Answer (score 3):

The [GNU `diff` documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/diffutils/manual/html_node/Detailed-Unified.html) explains this, in the section on *Unified Format*:

> Next come one or more hunks of differences; each hunk shows one area
>   where the files differ. Unified format hunks look like this:
>
> ```
>  @@ from-file-line-numbers to-file-line-numbers @@
>   line-from-either-file
>   line-from-either-file...
> ```
>
> If a hunk contains just one line, only its start line number appears.
>   Otherwise its line numbers look like ‘start,count’. An empty hunk is
>   considered to start at the line that follows the hunk.
>
> If a hunk and its context contain two or more lines, its line numbers
>   look like ‘start,count’. Otherwise only its end line number appears.
>   An empty hunk is considered to end at the line that precedes the hunk.
>
> The lines common to both files begin with a space character. The lines
>   that actually differ between the two files h ave one of the following
>   indicator characters in the left print column:
>
> ```
> ‘+’
>    A line was added here to the first file. 
> ‘-’
>    A line was removed here from the first file.
> ```

Comment: Thanks. What does "hunk" mean here?

Comment: @Tim the common English meaning of "a piece of something" works well.

Comment: A piece of what here?

Comment: @Tim since it says "hunks of differences", what do you think?

Comment: It's the section of output between lines beginning `@@` or `---` or `+++`

Comment: @Sukminder presumable you take the "hot guy" meaning. Anyway, OED considers chunk to be the prime synonym of hunk: http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/hunk